# Regular expression for Avoiding equal ,Consecutive numbers

Tags: regex

i am trying to build for the following criteria

```
     The following captures should not be allowed:

       1) Null fields
       2) Field captured as “000000”
       3) Field captured with consecutive numbers “123456”
       4) Field captured with equal numbers  “111111”
       5) input length is 7 digits not less or more
```

> Regex Used =  `^(?!([0-9]{7})).$`

```
Examples:- 

1111111 1234567 456789 0000000 we invalid successfully 

VALID like 8563241 5342861 all the valid scenarios are also not working .
Could any one help me how to capture valid scenarios with a regular expression .
```

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: I feel like you can get some more response/answers if you can brush up your actual question with some better/clear descriptions of what you are after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229582/discussion-between-prasad-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some chat we accomplished the following rules, where input:

- Must be exactly 7 digits.
- Can't contain any three of the same repetitive characters, e.g: "111".
- Can't contain any three consecutive numbers (forward/reversed), e.g: "123" or "321".

---

Therefor, it seems the following does tick your boxes:

```
^(?!.*?(?:012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210|(\d)\1\1))\d{7}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAvYgw/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead:

  - `.*?` - 0+ characters (lazy).
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210` - All the alternatives to avoid anywhere in your input.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `(\d)\1\1` - A single digit captured with two backreferences to the same group.
  - `))` - Close non-capture group and negative lookahead.
- `\d{7}` - 7 Digits.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: for now upvoted .. will accept it in some time after  precise testing. Thanq Mr.Pro Jvdv